# React component is not being displayed on browser, getting empty screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script><!--core react library-->
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><!--help us inject react into the dom-->

<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       

    </div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    class App extends React.Component{
       render(){
          
            return <div>Helo</div>
        }
    }
    let divapp=document.getElementById('app')
    ReactDom.render(<App />,divapp);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried everything I could, searched a lot of answers, but none of them helped, I just can't understand why my code is not working, I have cross checked me code with instructor's code, still i am having a blank screen before me, kindly help.

Comment: check this once https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need `bable.js` CDN in `head` tag too.
2. `ReactDOM` not `ReactDom`

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script><!--core react library-->
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><!--help us inject react into the dom-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       

    </div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    class App extends React.Component{
       render(){
          
            return <div>Helo</div>
        }
    }
    let divapp=document.getElementById('app')
    ReactDOM.render(<App />,divapp);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked, your solution worked. I don't know why we needed to include Babel script as well, but somehow it worked. Also I feel so stupid to have written ReactDom instead of ReactDOM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to follow the create-react-app approach which is very simple and easy way to start with reactjs.

Check this out.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Under the :

> Setup Option 2: Local Development Environment

Take a look on the :

> Instructions for following along locally using your preferred text
>   editor

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>


  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/babel">
            class App extends React.Component {
              render() {

                      return <div>Helo</div>
                  }
              }
              let divapp=document.getElementById('app')
              ReactDOM.render(<App />,divapp);
    </script>
    <div id="app">    
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please add babel library file in the header section or copy and run this code.